# How to default display currency change?

Tags: magento2, currency

I got error (not available in allowed currencies)

***Sorry, the default display currency you selected is not available in allowed currencies*.**
[image]

Comment: You can see the selected values in database -> 'core_config_data'. It would be saved on the following path: for allowed currencies: currency/options/allow

for base currency: currency/options/base

for default currency: currency/options/default

Comment: Hello @KGR, did my solution worked Or you need further help ?

Comment: @Pawan it not working

Comment: did you select "US Dollar" in the multiselect. ?

Answer (score 2):

It is happening because you are selecting "US Dollar" as default display currency, but you have **not** select "US Dollar" in allowed currency.

**You need to Add US Dollar to allowed currency**

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**You just need to Select your store from top:**

*Then set your allowed currency for your current store and save.*

Comment: i already select Default config